# Error While trying to stream encrypted video using exoplayer

Tags: android, encryption, video-streaming, exoplayer2.x

I have been trying to stream encrypted video on my server using exoplayer. 
I figured out everything about the custom data source and it is streaming other online videos which are not encrypted but when I am trying to decrypt the video I am getting an error
I only know the password string (Which is "abc123" I also have md5 of this)and I have no idea how should I exactly convert it to the key and then use it with my cipher 
Error 1) When I am using password string as the key I am getting unsupported key size error,
2) When I am using md5 as key I am getting UnrecognizedInputFormatException

```
    String sb="abc123"; 
    byte []b=sb.getBytes();
    mSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(b,"AES");
    mIvParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec("abc123".getBytes());
    try {
        mCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        mCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mSecretKeySpec,mIvParameterSpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()+e.getCause()+"fuckeddd");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

“abc123” is not a valid encryption key. An encryption key is a 16 byte binary value.

Comment: what should I do? The client only provided me the password "abc123" and md5 which is 32 bytes